# How to replace all substrings with other string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am loading data and then putting it in an input, the data that it enters goes under the name "Business Type" and I need to change that to "businessTypeId"

for example

actually I have

```
[{"URL":"http://www.restaurant.com","Business Type":1},{"URL":"http://www.hotel.com","Business Type":2}]
```

I would like to:

1. replace all `"Business Type"` to `"businessTypeId"`
2. `[delete square brackets]`
3. add `""` to id (id is the number in Business Type)

this is the espected result

```
{"url":"http://www.restaurant.com","businessTypeId":"1"},{"url":"http://www.hotel.com","businessTypeId":"2"}
```

this is my code

```
placesArray.push(JSON.stringify(results.data));
console.log(placesArray);
document.getElementById('places').value = placesArray;
```

`placesArray` contains the string that I would like to change

Comment: What do you expect from ```placesArray.push(JSON.stringify(results.data));```, and what does ```console.log(placesArray);``` log afterwards? As it is an array of string(s), it simply can not be what is shown as "actually I have".

Comment: that console log is for testing only, ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data=
[{"URL":"http://www.restaurant.com","Business Type":1},{"URL":"http://www.hotel.com","Business Type":2}]

//"Buisness Type" is a key, so firstly, go through each index, then in each index search through its keys and do replacing stuffs
data.forEach(a=>{
  Object.keys(a).forEach(b=>{
    if(b=="Business Type"){//what you want replaced
      var n=a[b].toString() //value to put in replaced key(and to string because you told me that you want string data not number data)
      delete(a[b]) //deleting old key
      a["businessTypeId"]=n //adding replaced key with previous value
    }
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: thanks! but I get a result with [square brackets], I have to delete that [], with your code I had to use JSON.stringify(data); because the result was [object][object]. How can I delete that []? and I have to add "" to id number. for example "businessTypeId":"1"

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma for the first thing.. trying to put data into an HTML element would do something like that.. secondly, for the turning `1` to `"1"` consider that done

Comment: when I put the result in an input, puts it with the brackets

Comment: I solved adding this .toString().replace(/^\[([\s\S]*)]$/,'$1')

Answer (score 2):

You could use the array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const data = [
  { "URL":"http://www.restaurant.com", "Business Type": 1},
  { "URL":"http://www.hotel.com", "Business Type": 2 },
];

const result = data.map(value => ({
  url: value.URL,
  businessTypeId: value["Business Type"]?.toString(),
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: That happens if the `Business Type` field is missing in one of the array values. I'll update my answer to account for the missing field.

Comment: thanks, that works, but when I tried to change the string to my placesArray I get an [object Object] result, and if I use JSON.stringify(result) I get only this [{}]